# Work done by moving up an inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Suppose an object is pushed up a smooth inclined plane from ground level to a point **h** above the ground with force **F**. The angle of inclination is **A**. How much work is done?

To push an object up a smooth inclined plane, one must overcome the force of gravity which causes the object to slide down the plane. Hence, the force **F=mgsinA** must be applied. We can denote the distance the body undergoes as **s=hsinA**, then:

**W=Fs=mg(sinA)^2**

The answer is **mgh** and I know that this can be easily proven using energy conservation laws, but I want to know why my method is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You've made a mistake in calculating the displacement component for the object.
If you observe, $S\neq hsinA$

$$S=\frac{h}{\sin A}$$

and therefore, the work done, is:

$$F.s=\left(mg\sin A\right)\left(\frac{h}{\sin A}\right)=mgh$$

which is the exact expression you got from energy conservation.

Answer (score 0):

Work done on a object by definition is $W = \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{S}$. This is a vector product so you can **project one vector on the another** to get the result. At first you were projecting the force $\mathbf{F}$ on the displacement $\mathbf{S}$. You got the answer here and projecting the displacement on the vertical axis and multiply it by the force along the slope is meaningless.