# Work-energy theorem and inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

I am trying to understand the work-energy theorem, and on my book there is the following example which I find a bit confusing:

A point of mass $m$ moves up from the lowest part of on an inclined plane with initial velocity $v_{0}$. Find the height at which the point stops.

So the solution is just $\frac{1}{2}mv_{0}^2 = mgh$ and then it easy to find h.

My doubt is about the fact that is just uses $h$ instead of $h \cos\theta$. Is it because work is a scalar quantity? Or because it's a conservative force?

Thanks a lot

Edit: sorry, found answer here: [Work done by moving up an inclined plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187648/work-done-by-moving-up-an-inclined-plane)

Comment: Definitely $h$. The change in potential gravitational energy if clearly $mgh$, not $mgh\cos\theta$. The change in height is $h$, not $h\cos\theta$.

Comment: shouldn't it be $mghsin\theta$, as it's explained in the question i linked?

Comment: Yes, I copied the $\cos$ from your question.

Comment: Yes that was wrong cause I still get a bit confused